# Error trying to test a Django form

Tags: django

I'm trying to write a test for this form:

```py
class UserCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), max_length=254, required=True)
    is_admin = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"),
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                help_text=_("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

    permissions = PermissionMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Permission.objects.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(get_user_model()),
                                                                                   codename__regex='^can_(view|manage)_.*'),
                                                widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

But when I do, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  (...)
  File "/Users/tapia/src/axpo-em/energymanager/adminpanel/forms.py", line 55, in <module>
    class UserCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/Users/tapia/src/axpo-em/energymanager/adminpanel/forms.py", line 64, in UserCreateForm
    permissions = PermissionMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Permission.objects.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(get_user_model()),
  (...)
OperationalError: no such table: django_content_type
```

The weird thing is, if I paste the queryset that raises the error in the test, it works perfectly:

```
class UserCreateFormTest(TestCase):
    def test_user_create_form(self):
        print ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Client)
        print Permission.objects.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(get_user_model()),
                                  codename__regex='^can_(view|manage)_.*')
```

This is driving me crazy. Any idea, please?

**UPDATE**

I've seen that if I write the test this way, it works fine, but I don't know why, and it seems wrong (should I do the import for each test method???):

```
class UserCreateFormTest(TestCase):
    def test_user_create_form(self):

        # Why does the import must be inside the test method????
        from adminpanel.forms import UserCreateForm

        form = UserCreateForm(data={})
```

Comment: Have you got `django.contrib.contenttypes` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` (and have you run `syncdb`)?

Comment: Yes, it's in INSTALLED_APPS. And how do I run syncdb in an in-memory sqlite DB?

Comment: Anyway, if that were the problem, the modified test I wrote in the last part of the question wouldn't word, would it?